# EPS created with matplotlib does not show text correctly

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib, eps

I have a Font problem in eps-files from matplotlib.

The font show correctly in die eps file, but when I paste the file in Microsoft Word, it doesnt Show the text (Labels, ticks, title...)

I already tryed to change the `maplotlib.rcParams` because that was the solution for other problems with text in eps files, but nothing worked.

EDIT: already changed `matplotlib.use("xxx")` too, did not help.

my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

plt.title("lalala",family='Courier New')
x = range(len(a))
y = range(len(a))
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = a

ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, cstride=1, rstride=1,alpha=0.3)

plt.savefig("texttestqua.eps")
plt.show()
```

is it possible to "draw" the text in the eps file? So that the text is not a "font" but just graphic-vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if your problem stems from the inability of matplotlib to save your eps correctly or the inability of Microsoft Word to load vector graphics other than emf/wmf... 
Nonetheless, I am giving it a try...

There are quite a lot of backends (GTK GTKAgg GTKCairo GTK3Agg GTK3Cairo CocoaAgg MacOSX Qt4Agg Qt5Agg TkAgg WX WXAgg Agg Cairo GDK PS PDF SVG), have you tried them all or at least a plausible subset?
Does it work for example with PS?

---

I am using the `TkAgg` backend here and your script produces the following output for me:
[image: screenshoted_eps_with_text]

---

> but when I paste the file in Microsoft Word, it doesnt Show the text (Labels, ticks, title...)

Afaik Microsoft Word does not support vector graphics natively unless it is emf. See [this link](https://superuser.com/a/979879) for further guidance.

If that does not solve your problem, please consider formulating an explicit problem.